# How to change the kernel of a jupyter notebook from the command line

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I know that one can switch the kernel of a Jupyter notebook from within the notebook itself, [for example](https://doc.cocalc.com/howto/jupyter-kernel-selection.html#jupyter-classic), by going to the `Kernel -> Change kernel` menu.

*I was just wondering if it's possible to do this programmatically with a shell script (or from command line).*

I have many Jupyter notebooks that were in python kernel and need to be changed to the R kernel. Doing the conversion manually for all of them would be tedious. I searched around, but only found answers about how to change kernel via the Jupyter UI as linked above.

(This is with Ubuntu 20.04, and classic JupyterHub)

Answer (score 1):

`.ipynb` files are, in fact, valid JSON. As kernel is saved in notebook metadata, you can edit it in text mode programmatically using Python itself, or with your favourite tool, for example `jq`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to solve what I *believe* is the same problem.  I don't want to edit the .json -- I want to tell it what kernel to use to *override* the one named in the "name" field in the notebook .json file.

I've tried:

```
ipython kernel install --name "foo_env" --prefix=./foo_env
```

(which installs the kernel locally in the virtual environment I want to use, instead of `--user`, which is what I want) and foo_env shows up in `jupyter kernelspec list` in the activated virtual environment.

and then:

```
jupyter-notebook foo_notebook.ipynb --MultiKernelManager.default_kernel_name=foo_env
```

But this still doesn't override the kernel name in the notebook (which is `"python3"`).

The running notebook knows about the `foo_env` kernel, as well, just doesn't actually use it at startup.