# Can't load OSMnx in Juypter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, osmnx

I can't import osmnx into my jupyter notebook (python version 3.8.8). I've run the following code:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx jupyterlab
conda activate ox
python -m ipykernel install --user --name ox --display-name "Python (ox)"
jupyter lab
```

Which just opens a new notebook in a new tab and osmnx only works in that tab. I'm looking to be able to install osmnx into my already saved notebook. I tried this in my working tab

```
pip install osmnx
```

but it gives the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-9-8ead41cb7306>", line 3
    pip install osmnx
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and

```
import osmnx as ox
```

gives the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d4a103aeed40> in <module>
----> 1 import osmnx as ox

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osmnx'
```

You might think "just use the new tab" but the new tab is incredibly slow (it's practically not functioning) and I can't save it either.

Anyone know how to successfully import osmnx into a jupyter notebook?

Comment: Can't help much as I am struggling with a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72804507/osmnx-1-2-1-for-jupyter-notebooks

Comment: What do you mean by "install osmnx into my already saved notebook"? Packages are not installed into notebooks. A notebook merely uses a kernel that provides an environment containing your desired packages. Have you set your notebook to use your new  "Python (ox)" kernel?

Comment: @gboeing I think that's my question, how to do this "Have you set your notebook to use your new "Python (ox)" kernel?"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64589345/how-to-change-the-kernel-of-a-jupyter-notebook-from-the-command-line

Comment: Ok thank you I didn't know about kernels, I've done some reading to try understand them more. For anyone else: To solve my issue I created a new notebook, manually changed the kernel from the top panel and copied my code over.